# MessageSecurityException Незащищенное или неправильно защищенное сообщение об ошибке было получено от другой стороны

Tags: c#, mvc, wcf, безопасность

Есть метод, который создает прокси сервиса:

```
    private static T GetServiceProxy<T>(SecurityToken token)
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<T>("*");
        return factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
    }
```

И имеется блок кода, в котором создаем прокси и вызываем метод:

```
// 1 - basicHttpBinding 
IBasicService basicService = GetServiceProxy<IBasicService>(st);
var dataBasic = basicService.Method(); 
// 2 - ws2007FederationHttpBinding     
IWsFedService wsFedService = GetServiceProxy<IWsFedService>(st);
var dataWsFed = wsFedService.Method();
```

Конфигурационный файл сайта содержит:

```
<binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:25:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="BearerKey">
              <issuer address="https://xxx/issue/wstrust/message/username" />
              <issuerMetadata address="https://xxx/issue/wstrust/mex" />
              <tokenRequestParameters>
                <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                  <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
                  <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
                  <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
                </trust:SecondaryParameters>
              </tokenRequestParameters>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Имеется thinktecture identity server v2. Разбирая пример на двух привязках:

1. basicHttpBinding - (IBasicService)
2. ws2007FederationHttpBinding - (IWsFedService)

В первом случае все работает хорошо, после вызова метода сервиса я получаю данные. Во втором случае после вызова метода я получаю исключение:

> An exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Незащищенное или неправильно защищенное
>   сообщение об ошибке было получено от другой стороны. Код ошибки и
>   описание см. внутреннее исключение.

Если зайти в InnerException, то там содержится такое сообщение:

> Ошибка при обработке токенов безопасности в сообщении.

Ничего более там нет, кроме этого сообщения. Во время Attach через Remote Debugger, к WCF-сервисам на сервере никаких ошибок не падает. То есть - если я вызываю метод сервиса с привязкой basicHttpBinding - то я вижу подключение и могу в режиме отладки все посмотреть. Но как только я подключаюсь через ws2007FederationHttpBinding - я даже до сервисов не дохожу и на локальной машине отлавливаю исключение в проекте MVC. В Thinktecture ничего не падает, там я также в режиме отладки. 
**Что это за ошибка и как ее лечить?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с WCF-сервисами по защищенному соединению в проекте MVC в файл **Global.asax** добавил следующую строку:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   ...
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
   ...
}
```

В WCF-сервисах внес изменения в конфигурационный файл, поменял тип безопасности с **Message** на **TransportWithMessageCredential**:

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false"
                     issuedKeyType="BearerKey">
              <issuerMetadata address="https://xxx/issue/wstrust/mex" />
              <issuer address="https://xxx/issue/wstrust/message/username"></issuer>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
```

И немного увеличил таймауты. Еще добавил в **Identity.config** мэнеджер:

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>

    <claimsAuthorizationManager type="xxx.AuthorizationManager, xxx" />
    ...
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

Содержимое самого менеджера для начала сделал примитивно простым. Затем можно будет дополнительно настроить безопасность с помощью него, но пока все выглядит так:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;

public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
    {
        public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            Collection<Claim> resource = context.Resource;
            Collection<Claim> action = context.Action;
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = context.Principal;
            IIdentity пользователь = principal.Identity;
            return true;
            //return base.CheckAccess(context);
        }
    }
```

Также, в файле конфигурации сервисов, для каждого сервиса задал описания, по какой привязке будет работать каждый:

```
<services>
      <service name="xxx.WsFedService">
        <endpoint contract="xxx.Interfaces.IWsFedService" 
                  binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"/>
      <service name="xxx.BasicService">
        <endpoint contract="xxx.Interfaces.IBasicService" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
      ...
      </service>
</services>
```

Пожалуй, самой главной проблемой, оказалась кодировка файла конфигурации. Немного ранее я настраивал все на тестовом стенде и все работало. Но у нас в проекте произошли некоторые изменения и мы перешли с VS2013 на VS2015. Понадобился один день, чтобы найти причину. Я просто взял и написал весь конфиг руками с нуля. Конфиг оказался почти копией того, что был ранее, но все же я внес некоторые изменения, которые описал в ответе. В общем - все работает так как нужно и я буду рад, если кому-то смог помочь решить подобную проблему.